# Why does "\x-1" not work in node name?

Tags: nodes, foreach, pgfmath

How to fix the error in referring to a node using `\x-1`?

It works in `[below left = \x-1]` but does not work in `\draw[->] (\x-1) to (\x)`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.00cm and 0.10cm, 
    every node/.style = {draw, circle, fill = blue!20}]

  \node (1) {$1$};

  \foreach \x in {2, ..., 7} {
    \node (\x) [below left = \x-1] {$\x$};
    \draw[->] (\x-1) to (\x);     % not work: no shape named 2-1 
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: foreach-node-name]

I have also tried

```
\foreach \x [remember = \x as \lastx] in {2, ..., 7} {
    \node (\x) [below left = \x-1] {$\x$};
    \draw[->] (\lastx) to (\x);   % not work: undefined control sequence. \lastx }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\x-1` gets evaluated as `2-1` etc. Ti*k*Z does not (necessarily) expect a number at this position, for good reasons. Instead of `1.north` you could also write `1.90`, for `1.east` `1.0` and so on. So if Ti*k*Z was to interpret the node name as number, it would really become ambiguous.

However, I do not have an issue with `remember` if I add an appropriate initial value (for the first step).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.00cm and 0.10cm, 
    every node/.style = {draw, circle, fill = blue!20}]

  \node (1) {$1$};

  \foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially 1)] in {2, ..., 7} {
    \node (\x) [below left = \x-1] {$\x$};
    \draw[->] (\lastx) to (\x);     % not work: no shape named 2-1 
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 (first use of *remember* for me). Where is this documented? I would like to read more about it.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, se "83 Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement" in tikz & pgf manual (v3.0.1a), page 901. function is described on page 905.

Answer (score 7):

`\x-1` is not evaluated inside a node's name postition, but you can force some evaluations inside the optional parameter of a `\foreach` construction.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.00cm and 0.10cm, 
    every node/.style = {draw, circle, fill = blue!20}]

  \node (1) {$1$};

  \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \nx using {int(\x-1)}] in {2, ..., 7} {
    \node (\x) [below left = of \nx] {$\x$};
    \draw[->] (\nx) to (\x);     % not work: no shape named 2-1 
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: I've also added `of` in positioning construction (you are loading `positioning` library) and the result is a little bit different.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can force complete integer evaluation with `\numexpr`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.00cm and 0.10cm, 
    every node/.style = {draw, circle, fill = blue!20}]

  \node (1) {$1$};

  \foreach \x in {2, ..., 7} {
    \node (\x) [below left = \x-1] {$\x$};
    \draw[->] (\the\numexpr\x-1\relax) to (\x);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]